# Delete rows based off adjacent cell value- VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm having trouble with this bit of code to delete rows that don't represent an actual minimum. It simply does not work, I have hand verified the logic. What I'm trying to check is if the value of the cell in row 1, column 2 is greater than row 2, column 2. and if that is the case, then delete row 1 entirely. I have found examples where they loop similarly to this, but look for a certain string value rather than compare the cells value with a  logic statement. I have done a check to make sure it is referencing the correct worksheet and that I understand how the delete function works. I have also tested the code with `LRow + 1` instead of `LRow - 1`. What am I doing wrong?

```
Sub rowdelete()
Dim LRow As Long
With Worksheets("WWOutput")
        For LRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp) To Cells(7, 2) Step -1
            If Cells(LRow, 2) > Cells(LRow - 1, 2) And Cells(LRow, 2) < 10000 Then
        Rows(LRow).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
 Next LRow
End With
End Sub
```

Here is some sample data.

```
11804.6875
6415.625095
6333.593845
3786.718845
11841.40682
```

In this case all I want to be left for data is

```
11804.6875
3786.718845
11841.40682
```

Thank you ahead of time!

Comment: `make sure it is referencing the correct worksheet` but it's not when you forget the `.` before the `cells` when using `with`.

Comment: change `For LRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp) To Cells(7, 2) Step -1` to `For LRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row To 7 Step -1`

Comment: ahh, something so little makes such a big difference. Thank you @findwindow and Scott! As I'm trying to learn more about VBA coding, what difference does the `.` make?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like they said...

```
Sub rowdelete()
    Dim LRow As Long
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        For LRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row To Cells(7, 2).Row Step -1
            If .Cells(LRow, 2) > .Cells(LRow - 1, 2) And (.Cells(LRow, 2) < 10000) Then
                .Rows(LRow).EntireRow.Delete
            End If
        Next LRow
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: `To Cells(7, 2).Row` you missed Scott's comment.

Comment: Ah yes ... you can just skip that and replace with the actual row number